How can I convert age from string to number without compilation error?
I am facing a problem while trying to convert a string to a number. I have an age property in my JsType which is of type number, but I'm mapping an array of JsonType, which has a property age of type number:
interface JsType{
    name: string
    age?: number
     //... more fields
}
interface JsonType{
    name: string
    age?: string
    //... more fields
}
const filterData: JsType[] = [{name: 'magnus'}, {name:'hikaru',age: "50"}].map((item: JsonType): JsType => {
    //item.age is of type string, i want it to be of type number
    let age: number | null = item.age ? Number(item.age):null
    let obj = {...(age?{age}:{}) }
    const doc = { ...item, ...obj }
    return doc
    //ts error
    // Types of property 'age' are incompatible.
    // Type 'string | number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'.
    //   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
})

The compilation error happens when returning doc object:
Types of property 'age' are incompatible.
     Type 'string | number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'.
         Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

How can I convert the string without getting the compilation error?

You should not use a string, or a number to store the age of someone, because next year the age will be invalid.  You can use a date, which can be used to calculate the age.

follow up question: What if I have 2 huge objects, How I can tell typescript to infer the type of second object if both a the object have same key. {...hugeOjbect_1, hugeObject_2}, have 100 common key all with different types,

Your follow up post should have been posted as a new question, but only after doing some research (like visiting, and reading: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=typescript+infer+type+from+object+ )

Your Javascript is wrong too if you want to be strict. What you try is to add age only when it's truthy, but you leave it in ...item in case it for example an empty string.
So I would suggest the following (removing age by destructuring):
interface JsType{
    name: string
    age?: number
     //... more fields
}
interface JsonType{
    name: string
    age?: string
    //... more fields
}
const filterData: JsType[] = [{name: 'magnus'}, {name:'hikaru',age: "50"}].map((item: JsonType): JsType => {
    let age: string | undefined, out: JsType;
    ({age, ...out} = item);
    if(age) out.age = Number(age);
    return out;
})


The solution is simple, you're declaring a obj variable for no reason, just use this approach instead:
interface JsType{
    name: string
    age?: number
     //... more fields
}
interface JsonType{
    name: string
    age?: string
    //... more fields
}
const filterData: JsType[] = [{name: 'magnus'}, {name:'hikaru',age: "50.5"}].map((item: JsonType): JsType => {
    let age = item.age ? Number(item.age) : undefined;
    const doc = { ...item, age }
    return doc
})

this should work
